# What's wrong with my Stopwatch in Webforms? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I made a Webform that displays time and date, and I wanted to do the same for a Stopwatch, but for some reason the Stopwatch doesn't work.

The time is supposed to start ticking when I click "start", it's supposed to stop when I click "stop", and it is supposed to clear when I click "reset". Instead, when I click start, nothing happens.

Here is my code (C#):

```
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private short _secs, _ms;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timerz.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IncreaseMS();
        ShowTime();
    }

    private void IncreaseMS()
    {
        if (_ms == 99)
        {
            _ms = 0;
            IncreaseSecs();
        }
        else
        {
            _ms++;
        }
    }

    private void IncreaseSecs()
    {
        if (_secs == 59)
        {
            _secs = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            _secs++;
        }
    }

    protected void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start.Enabled = false;
        Timer2.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected void reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _secs = 0;
        _ms = 0;

        ShowTime();
    }

    private void ShowTime()
    {
        secsText.Text = _secs.ToString("00");
        msText.Text = _ms.ToString("00");
    }

    protected void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start.Enabled = true;
        Timer2.Enabled = false;
    }
}
}
```

Webform, ASP.NET Code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        Current time:
        <asp:Label ID="Timerz" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" 
OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
    </asp:Timer>
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="secsText" runat="server" Text="00"></asp:Label><asp:Label 
ID="colon" runat="server" Text=":"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="msText" 
runat="server" Text="00"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="start" runat="server" Text="Start" OnClick="start_Click" 
/><asp:Button ID="stop" runat="server" Text="Stop" OnClick="stop_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="reset" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="reset_Click" />
</div>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" OnTick="Timer2_Tick">
    </asp:Timer>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Webforms dont work the same way as windows form. Every time you click on a button the page is refreshed and a it's processed at the server and a new instance of form is genrated and rendered to browser. I think you should explore some client side script libraries to implement timer in web form.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I couldn't find any only documentation or tutorials about making a stopwatch or anything similar in Web Forms so I did it the Window Form way with tutorials.

Is there any library you recommend, or would it be easier to use JavaScript?

Comment: https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/ or https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the Interval property on Timer2. The default interval is 60 seconds and you are probably not waiting that long.

Comment: I just tried that, and when I changed the Timer2's intervals to 1, the timer just adds 1 to the last digit, and the broswer keeps refreshing extremely fast, but the timer never changes its value from 1.

Comment: @MarcGravell The ASP.Net timer control is not a server side timer. It is triggered by setTimeout on the client side

Comment: @AlGorithmGuy - 1ms is far too fast to round-trip to the server. You might get away with 2s. The next problem is that your state variable _secs and _ms are reset to zero every time the timer triggers and reloads the page. These problems can be solved but it looks (from your other comments) that you're going to do it client side - which is a much better idea anyway!

Comment: I tried it with 2000 intervals and it had a similar effect, I guess the _secs and _ms is a big issue like you said. I'll try it with JavaScript I guess.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, try making _secs and _ms static and you should see them increment. If you open the same page in 2 tabs you should see the same value incrementing twice as fast

Comment: I tried your suggestion and lowered the intervals to 100 to test it, the stopwatch now works, but it ticks so fast that I have to click stop many times to make it stop and if I don't press reset, it keeps the value even if I close the tab and reload it. It works, but it's unstable, I think you're right that I should try this client side, by that you mean JavaScript right?

Comment: Yes that was just to demonstrate that it can work, just badly. You should be able to get something working in javascript with a combination of Date.now() and setTimeout()